# Find indices of enclosing grid-points from bin index in an nd-array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have an nd-array of grid-points, `G`, and then an overlaying nd-array of bins `B`, as shown in the image below. The indices of `G` are shown in blue, and the indices of `B` are in red. Given the index of a bin (red), I would like to find the indices of the enclosing grid-points (blue).

[image: Example grid and bin arrays]

For example, given the bin index `7`, the enclosing grid-point indices would be `(1, 2, 5, 6)`.

I'm looking for a solution which should work for n-dimensional arrays, not just 2D arrays. I get the feeling this should be a problem that comes up quite often, but haven't found any solutions in numpy, and am struggling to come up with an elegant solution for n-dimensions.

Note that the number of indices for `B` is one greater than `G` along each array dimension.

---

Some test code

```py
import numpy as np
G = np.arange(3*4).reshape(3, 4)
B = np.arange(4*5).reshape(4, 5)
idx = 7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an solution, which should have occurred to me earlier. Everything is much easier if you unravel the index  first. I've annotated my original drawing with the unraveled indices.

[image]

The unraveled bin-index is always the furthest-most corner of the grid, so you can take all combinations of of subtracting one position in each dimension, to find all other edges. This can be done easily and quickly with `itertools.product`. Note, you have to take care when using the indices, since querying bins that are outside the grid (such as `bin_idx=0` or `4`) will return invalid indices. This can be handled with `try` and `except` blocks when actually querying, as in @alec_djinn's answers.

```py
import numpy as np
import itertools as it


def get_grid_indices(bin_idx, bins_shape):
    bin_nrvld = np.unravel_index(bin_idx, bins_shape)
    grid_indices = list()
    dims = len(bins_shape)
    index_offsets = it.product([0, -1], repeat=dims)
    for offset in index_offsets:
        grid_indices.append(tuple(x + y for x, y in zip(bin_nrvld, offset)))
    return grid_indices


print('Two dimensional example')
blue_grid = np.arange(3*4).reshape(3, 4)
red_bins = np.arange(4*5).reshape(4, 5)
bin_idx = 7
grid_indices = get_grid_indices(bin_idx, red_bins.shape)
for idx in grid_indices:
    print('index: '+str(blue_grid[idx])+', unraveled: ', end='')
    print(np.unravel_index(blue_grid[idx], blue_grid.shape))

print('')
print('Three dimensional example')

blue_grid = np.arange(2*2*2).reshape(2, 2, 2)
red_bins = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3, 3, 3)
bin_idx = 13
grid_indices = get_grid_indices(bin_idx, red_bins.shape)

for idx in grid_indices:
    print('index: '+str(blue_grid[idx])+', unraveled: ', end='')
    print(np.unravel_index(blue_grid[idx], blue_grid.shape))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dictionary to associate the indices using the following code.

```
from collections import defaultdict

#Map indices
d = defaultdict(list)
for n,row in enumerate(G):
    for i,idx in enumerate(row):
        for j in range(2): #check current and next row
            d[idx].append(B[n+j][i]) #current row
            try:  #next row (or next number) may not exist
                #next row
                #[i+1] is the index of the next number in the row
                d[idx].append(B[n+j][i+1]) 
            except IndexError:
                pass
```

Which will create

```
>>> d
defaultdict(list,
            {0: [0, 1, 5, 6],
             1: [1, 2, 6, 7],
             2: [2, 3, 7, 8],
             3: [3, 4, 8, 9],
             4: [5, 6, 10, 11],
             5: [6, 7, 11, 12],
             6: [7, 8, 12, 13],
             7: [8, 9, 13, 14],
             8: [10, 11, 15, 16],
             9: [11, 12, 16, 17],
             10: [12, 13, 17, 18],
             11: [13, 14, 18, 19]})
```

Then just look for `idx` in the values of the dict.

```
#Search value
idx = 7 #red bin
r = []
for k,v in d.items():
    if idx in v:
        r.append(k)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(r) #blue bins sorrounding idx
[1, 2, 5, 6]
```

Comment: This seems fine for the toy-example I posted, but I'm looking for something that can work for nd-arrays of arbitrary dimensions, not just 2 dimensions. Further, they tend to have relatively high resolution, so generating a look-up table is a bit more involved, and takes up a lot of memory. I'm basically looking for something that will compute one of the entries in `d`.

Comment: Also, btw, I'm trying go from the bins (**red**) to the grid-points (**blue**), not the other way around.

Comment: @SteveHeim the search part is doing exactly that, you input the red bin, `7`, and you have the list of blue bins back `[1, 2, 5, 6]`. Exactly like the example you posted.

Comment: @SteveHeim About your first comment, the approach I proposed is quite general, you can extend it into multidimensional arrays quite easily. You can iteratively iterate over nested arrays. If you add a clear example of how a 3D array would look like, I'll be happy to adapt the code.

Comment: Aha, I misunderstood it as a look-up table, with 7 returning [8, 9, 13, 14], and missed the search part. One issue, if I'm understanding this correctly, is that you'd still have to generate the entire dict `d` in order to do the search. For higher dimensions, this will be quite large... I think I'm close to a solution as well, will post back if it works. I'll look into this one also.

Comment: @SteveHeim Yes, this method is based on generating a look-up table, which can be memory intensive depending on your array.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally come up with an alternative method which does not require building a look-up table.
However, you need to reshape the arrays to make it work.

```
red = np.array([[np.nan, x] for row in B for x in row]).reshape(4,10)
blue = np.array([[x,np.nan] for row in G for x in row]).reshape(3,8)


def f(red, blue, idx):
    i,j = [n[0] for n in np.where(red==idx)]
    r = []
    k = max(0,i-1)
    w = max(0,j-3)
    try:
        r.append(blue[k][w:j])
    except IndexError:
        pass
    try:
        r.append(blue[i][w:j])
    except IndexError:
        pass
    r = set([int(n) for n in flatten(r) if not np.isnan(n)])
    return r



for idx in range(20):
    print(idx, f(red, blue, idx))
```

The result is:

```
0 {0}
1 {0, 1}
2 {1, 2}
3 {2, 3}
4 {3}
5 {0, 4}
6 {0, 1, 4, 5}
7 {1, 2, 5, 6}
8 {2, 3, 6, 7}
9 {3, 7}
10 {8, 4}
11 {8, 9, 4, 5}
12 {9, 10, 5, 6}
13 {10, 11, 6, 7}
14 {11, 7}
15 {8}
16 {8, 9}
17 {9, 10}
18 {10, 11}
19 {11}
```

Here the code for `flatten()`

```
def flatten(l):
    '''
    Flat an iterable.
    '''
    for item in l:
        try:
            yield from flatten(item)
        except TypeError:
            yield item
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a working solution yesterday evening, just posted it. I haven't tested yours for comparison yet, I'll try to come back to this after my upcoming deadline :)